# Visual Studio 2015 CE Setup Installer: Redistributable Package

Tags: vdproj

I have my my setup project in (Visual Studio 2015: Community Edition) ready to be built and create my program installer. But, obviously the program will not work on other computers without the appropriate redistributable package installed on the clients computer.

So, I need to set that up in my project but I do not know how. I read in a post on another site that it is located in:

> Project>>Setup Properties>>Prerequisites

But, all I just see are selectables for ".net framework" related things. Also, I read that merge modules are not good to use due to servicing issues.

If you have any insight into whether I am needing to download an extension for the correct prerequisite to appear, use merge modules, or something else it will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you link that website if possible?

Comment: @cybermonkey Which one?